# compiling a dynamic library with only a declared function

Tags: macos, dynamic

This code compile under linux but not under mac osx (content of lib.c follows):

```
int add(int a, int b);

int sum(int a, int b) {return add(a, b);}
```

in linux I use this command and it works:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC lib.c -o lib.so
```

The same command fails in mac osx giving this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
>    "_add", referenced
>   from:
>         _sum in ccK5mZfC.o
>  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Could you please propose me a gcc option or an option to check in the Xcode IDE to solve this?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can build a shared library with an unresolved static external in the toolchain.

You will need to do one of the following:

- Link in the module containing add statically
- Link in the module containing add dynamically
- Include the add function in the shared library you are building

Otherwise the shared library will contain an unresolved, and unresolvable external, since the loader can't "fix up" the reference from the shared library to the code that it is being linked into.

*Updated for question on "position independent code":*

This isn't a question of position independence, it's a question of the loader being able to locate the named symbol during loading.  Although this may be allowed in linux, in OSX (FreeBSD and MACH-based), the loader expects the symbols in a shared library to resolve either internally, or via another shared library, for which stubs are known.

You can certainly build a static (.o) library without explicit references to every object, but to build a shared (.so) library, you will need to make sure that every referenced symbol is either contained within the library or has an external reference that the loader can resolve at load-time.

Comment: -fPIC option for Position Independent Code allows this on linux